# Catching pressing "Back" button in mvvmlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

How can i move

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
```

to the viewmodel and still be able to control "back'ing"? In the codebehind, i can use *e.Cancel = true;*, but how to use it in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind something that isn't bindable per say. All you can do is either create a fake binding using a `Behavior<T>`, but not much point in that.

Instead you could just simply forward the event in the ViewModel, doing something like:

```
e.OnCancel = ViewModel.OnBackKeyPress();
```

And then have `OnBackKeyPress()` return a `bool`.

Comment: But looking like messaging is exactly the thing, which was designed to prevent having access from view to viewmodel :) Right now i'm looking at messaging documentation... i guess, i saw a callback somewhere, so i'd be able to return bool with message.

Comment: Except messaging is async, and OnBackKeyPress is synchronous.

Answer (score 0):

The very first idea that i got - is to leave it in codebehind, and send message to viewmodel, so it should shange its state. But i'd still prefer to bind event to VM.